# Twig files are not rendered after update (dev envitoment require clearing cache)

Tags: caching, twig, symfony4

I merged some changes I had on other branch and since then I can't render twig changes on the server. Even though I have APP_ENV=dev in .env and files are uploaded I have to clear cache every time to see update.

My `twig.yaml` is like this:

```
twig:
    paths: ['%kernel.project_dir%/templates']
    debug: '%kernel.debug%'
    strict_variables: '%kernel.debug%'
```

In symfony 4 I don't think I need to set anything else to switch to dev env but I have no clue what I did wrong.

Also, cleaning cache by command doesn't work, I have to manually remove folder from the server (in var/cache I have only "dev" folder)

---

Very interesting thing... The next day I just sat to the project and it appear to work normally. I have no idea what could have been wrong, but it works!